# How do you call a stored procedure in EF Core and return the results using a generic class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can you call a stored procedure using Entity Framework Core and return the results using a generic class?

In .NET Standard Entity Framework, I'm able to call stored procedures and return generic like so:

```cs
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(object[] sqlParameters) where T : IStoredProcedure, new()
{
    if (sqlParameters == null) sqlParameters = new object[] { };
    return DataContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>((new T()).Query, sqlParameters).ToList();
}
```

This method is not available in the same fashion in Entity Framework Core anymore...

Comment: Improve your question and it will be reopened. Otherwise good answer will be hidden.

Comment: Question has been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Code First and are comfortable with the steps necessary to create the actual stored procedure and have that defined in your database, I will focus my answer on how to call that stored procedure in C# and map the results generically.

First you want to create a model that matches the data you expect to get back from your results.

Here is an example:

```cs
public class UserTimesheet : IStoredProcedure
{
    public string Query => "[dbo].[GetUserTimesheet] @userId, @month, @year";

    public DateTime WorkDate { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string? ProjectName { get; set; }
    public decimal? Hours { get; set; }
}
```

Notice this extends an interface called `IStoredProcedure` with the `Query` property. More on that later, but it's there to work by convention.

Here is that interface:

```cs
public interface IStoredProcedure
{
    string Query { get; }
}
```

Next you'll want to add a DbSet to your database context.

```cs
// Put this in your Database Context
public DbSet<UserTimesheet> UserTimesheets { get; set; } = null!;
```

Now since this doesn't map to an actual table, you will want to add some code to the `OnModelCreating` to tell EF how to reference it. Again, I'm working on a convention, in this case I only want to apply this setting to models that implement `IStoredProcedure`, and we can do that with a little reflection to make life easier.

In this case we're going to say it has no key and treat it like a view. I created an extension method to keep things a little cleaner, you can use it like this:

```cs
public static class ModelBuilderExtension
{
    public static ModelBuilder ConfigureStoredProcedureDbSets(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (typeof(IStoredProcedure).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasNoKey().ToView(null);
            }
        }

        return modelBuilder;
    }
}


// Put this in DatabaseContext class

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.ConfigureStoredProcedureDbSets();
}
```

Next you'll want something to hold your generic code. I use a class called `StoredProcedureRepository`, but you can call it what you like. Here's the code, including the interface (for Dependency Injection, if you like):

```cs
public abstract class Repository
{
    protected readonly DatabaseContext _context;

    protected Repository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}

public interface IStoredProcedureRepository
{
    IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(object[] sqlParameters) where T : class, IStoredProcedure, new();
    SqlParameter GetSqlParameter(string name, object value, bool isOutput = false);
}

public class StoredProcedureRepository : Repository, IStoredProcedureRepository
{
    #region Properties

    private const string SQL_PARAMETER_PREFIX = "@";

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public StoredProcedureRepository(DatabaseContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region Shared Public Methods

    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcedure<T>(object[] sqlParameters) where T : class, IStoredProcedure, new()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw<T>((new T()).Query, sqlParameters).ToList();
    }

    public SqlParameter GetSqlParameter(string name, object value, bool isOutput = false)
    {
        if (!name.StartsWith(SQL_PARAMETER_PREFIX))
        {
            name += SQL_PARAMETER_PREFIX;
        }

        var direction = isOutput ? System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output : System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

        return new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = name,
            Value = value,
            Direction = direction
        };
    }

    #endregion
}
```

There are a few things to notice here. It's referencing the DbSet generically and using `FromRawSql` and calling the `Query` (string) property from the `IStoredProcedure` implementation of your model. So you'll want to make sure that contains your query to execute the stored procedure, in this example that would be `"[dbo].[GetUserTimesheet] @userId, @month, @year"`

Now you can call this stored procedure generically.

Here is an example:

```cs
var parameters = new object[3];
parameters[0] = GetSqlParameter("@userId", userId);
parameters[1] = GetSqlParameter("@month", month);
parameters[2] = GetSqlParameter("@year", year);

IList<UserTimesheet> queryResults = _storedProcedureRepository.ExecuteStoredProcedure<UserTimesheet>(parameters).ToList();
```

To add new stored procedures, just create their respective models (being sure to implement `IStoredProcedure` and define their `Query` property, then add their `DbSet` to the database context.

For example:

```cs
public class UserProject : IStoredProcedure
{
    public string Query => "[dbo].[GetUserProjects] @userId";

    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
// add this to the database context
public DbSet<UserProject> UserProjects { get; set; } = null!;
```

then call it like so:

```cs
var parameters = new object[1];
parameters[0] = GetSqlParameter("@userId", userId);

IList<UserProject> queryResults = _storedProcedureRepository.ExecuteStoredProcedure<UserProject>(parameters).ToList();
```

Comment: `public DbSet<UserTimesheet> UserTimesheets { get; set; } = null!;` - it is  really needed?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - Do you mean the DbSet definition or default it to null?

Comment: I see, it is needed for `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`. But  you can just scan assembly for types.

Comment: Yes, without the DbSet being defined you'll get the following runtime exception when calling the generic method: `Cannot create a DbSet for 'UserTimesheet' because this type is not included in the model for the context.`